# How do I plot a hemisphere on top of a cone

Tags: plotting, geometry

```
RegionPlot3D[ Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= z && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 120, PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.8]]]
```

It gives me the result (Hemisphere on top on a cone ) I want but because I have never taken high level of math courses I do not have any explanation why I use `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= z`  as the equation for the cone. I will appreciate your kindness

Thanks

Comment: `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= c` where `c` is a constant defines a circle. So you can picture `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= z` as being a small circle when z is small and a larger circle when z is large. Hence, over the range of `z` values, you get the cone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how best to explain it, but I'll try.

`Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]` gives you a distance to (x, y) from the origin (0, 0) because it is the solution to the [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).  Viewed as a density plot it looks like this:

```
DensityPlot[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Dark values represent small distance while light values represent large distance.

If you plot this in three dimensions with the distance as height (z axis) you get a cone with square edges because you are plotting over a square region:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

To get a "normal" cone you need to cut the top off in a level line as viewed from the x and y axes.  To do this you could clip any value with a distance (z-value) greater than the radius of the circle that should make up the base of your cone:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
  RegionFunction -> (#3 < 2 &)]
```

[image]

Another way to express that is to limit the z-value to 2 by using `Min[2, z]`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Min[2, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Here the corners are not removed but instead flattened, and the circular base is again revealed.

Comment: @Maggie You're welcome.  If you are satisfied with an answer you can [Accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158428) it by clicking the check-mark to the left of it.